# Как вывести все статьи принадлежащих одному термину(тегу) таксономии Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть несколько кастомных таксономий у каждой из них есть от 5 до 10ти терминов(тегов). Под каждую таксономию у меня создан отдельный шаблон taxonomy-business.php.

На страницах таксономий я вывела заголовок страницы и все посты которые имеют термины принадлежащей конкретно этой таксономии

```
<?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => 6,
                'taxonomy' => 'business',
            );
            query_posts($args);
        ?>
```

На старнице выводится список из шести постов в которых содержится изображение, заголовок, термин(тег) и анонс.
Термин выводиться как ссылка и при нажатии на данный термин у меня меняется ссылка но по факту я остаюсь на той же странице с тем же самым списком постов.
Код вывода термина(тега) к которому относится статья

```
<?php 
                $cur_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'business' );
                if( is_array( $cur_terms ) ){
                  foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
                    echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $cur_term->term_id, $cur_term->taxonomy ) .'">'. $cur_term->name .'</a>';
                  }
                }
             ?>
```

И еще я вывожу термины в сайдбаре и у меня получается та же проблема, сами названия как ссылки выводятся в сайдбар но при нажатии на ссылку не происходит фильтрации.

Код который я использую для сайдбара

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud(
        $args = array (
            'largest'   => '12',
            'smallest'  => '12',
            'format'    => 'flat',
            'separator' => "\n",
            'orderby'   => 'name',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'exclude'   => null,
            'include'   => null,
            'link'      => 'view',
            'taxonomy'  => 'business',
            'echo'      => true,
            'topic_count_text_callback' => 'default_topic_count_text',
        )
    );?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно сделать что бы при нажатии на ссылку термина(тега) я получала страницу с постами которые принадлежат этому термину.
По сути мне нужно что бы мои кастомные таксономии работали так же как стандартные категории и подкатегории при нажатии на их ссылки мы получаем список постов принадлежащий конкретной категории или подкатегории.

Comment: вы обновляли пермалинки? можете добавить код создания таксономии?

Comment: Да сами линки я обновляла. Таксономии были созданы через плагин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проблему я решила и возможно кому то подойдет такой способ решения.
Я создала два php файла taxomomy-business.php и start-page-tax-busines.php.

start-page-tax-busines.php нужен для того что бы вывести список статей которые принадлежат терминам(тегам) таксономии busines.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Business-start-page
*/
$term = get_queried_object();
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
   
    
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    
        <h2 class="category-name">
            Business
        </h2>
// выводим список терминов таксономии business
    <div class="tag_taxonomy">
      <ul>
        <li>
    <?php wp_tag_cloud(
        $args = array (
            'largest'   => '12',
            'smallest'  => '12',
            'format'    => 'flat',
            'separator' => "\n",
            'orderby'   => 'name',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'exclude'   => null,
            'include'   => null,
            'link'      => 'view',
            'taxonomy'  => 'business',
            'echo'      => true,
            'topic_count_text_callback' => 'default_topic_count_text',
        )
    );?>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
        <?php
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args = array(
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page' => 12,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'business', // слаг таксономии
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => array( 'app-building', 'banking', 'coaching', 'corporate-messenger', 'e-commerce', 'education', 'healthcare', 'real-time-communication', 'security-compliance', 'social-networking', 'teleconsultation' ) // слаг термина или терминов которые нам нужны
                        )
                    ),
                );
                query_posts($args);
            ?>
              <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) { wp_paginate();}?>
//выводим список статей
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) :while ( have_posts() ) :the_post(); 
<!--posts--->

                    <!-- Post Content-->   
              
                    <!-- Thumbnail-->

// тут мы выводим термин к которому принадлежит статья из списка
                    
            <?php 
                $cur_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'business' );
                if( is_array( $cur_terms ) ){
                  foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
                    echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $cur_term->term_id, $cur_term->taxonomy ) .'">'. $cur_term->name .'</a>';
                  }
                }
             ?>
                    
//заголовок статьи
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 

        <?php endwhile ; ?>    
        <div class="list-item">
<!--paginate-->
              <?php the_posts_pagination(
              $args = array(
                'show_all'     => false, 
                'end_size'     => 0,     
                'mid_size'     => 1, 
                'prev_next'    => true, 
                'prev_text'    => __('Previous'),
                'next_text'    => __('Next'),
                'add_args'     => false, 
                'add_fragment' => '',  
                'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' ),
                'type' => 'list',
            )
              );
              ?>   
        </div>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif ; ?>
    
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

taxomomy-business.php нужен для того что бы выводить списки статей которые принадлежат тому или иному термину(тегу) кастомной таксономии

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: Business-Archive
*/
$term = get_queried_object();
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <h2>
// получаем имя термина(тега)
      <?php echo $term->name; ?>
        </h2>
    <?php
      $TaxArhive = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'business', указываем имя таксономии чьи термины мы должны получить
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
          )
          ),
      );
      $queryTaxPost = new WP_Query( $TaxArhive );
      ?>
      <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) { wp_paginate();}?>
      <?php if ( have_posts() ) :while ( have_posts() ) :the_post(); 
<!--posts--->

                    <!-- Post Content-->   
              
                    <!-- Thumbnail-->

                    <div class="cat">
// получаем список терминов к которым принадлежит статья из списка 
            <?php 
                $cur_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'business' );
                if( is_array( $cur_terms ) ){
                  foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
                    echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $cur_term->term_id, $cur_term->taxonomy ) .'">'. $cur_term->name .'</a>';
                  }
                }
             ?>
  //заголовок статьи из списка
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
     

        <?php endwhile ; ?>  
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>      
        <div class="list-item">
<!--paginate-->
              <?php the_posts_pagination(
              $args = array(
                'show_all'     => false, 
                'end_size'     => 0,     
                'mid_size'     => 1, 
                'prev_next'    => true, 
                'prev_text'    => __('Previous'),
                'next_text'    => __('Next'),
                'add_args'     => false, 
                'add_fragment' => '',  
                'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' ),
                'type' => 'list',
            )
              );
              ?>   
        </div>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif ; ?>
    
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Такое решение рабочие, но если у вас много таксономий как у меня то лучше создать единый архивный темплейт.
archive.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archive
*/
$term = get_queried_object();
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
//выводим имя термина
      <?php echo $term->name; ?>

    <?php
// создаем массив со списком таксономий
     $TaxItem = array ('my_tax1', 'my_tax2');

     $TaxArhive = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => $TaxItem, 
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
          )
          ),
      );
      $queryTaxPost = new WP_Query( $TaxArhive ); 
      ?>
      <?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) { wp_paginate();}?>
      <?php if ( have_posts() ) :while ( have_posts() ) :the_post(); 
<!--posts--->

                    <!-- Post Content-->   
              
                    <!-- Thumbnail-->

            <?php 
//перебираем список таксономий и выводим список статей с нужным термином
                foreach ($TaxItem as $tax) {
                  
                  switch ($tax) {
                    case 'my_tax1':
                    
                $cur_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $tax );
                if( is_array( $cur_terms ) ){
                  foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
                    echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $cur_term->term_id, $cur_term->taxonomy ) .'">'. $cur_term->name .'</a>';
                  }
                }

                  break;

                  case 'my_tax2':

                    $cur_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $tax );
                    if( is_array( $cur_terms ) ){
                    foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
                    echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $cur_term->term_id, $cur_term->taxonomy ) .'">'. $cur_term->name .'</a>';
                  }
                }
               
                break;
              }
            }
             ?>
                    //заголовок статьи
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
                    

        <?php endwhile ; ?>  
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>      
        <div class="list-item">
<!--paginate-->
              <?php the_posts_pagination(
              $args = array(
                'show_all'     => false, 
                'end_size'     => 0,     
                'mid_size'     => 1, 
                'prev_next'    => true, 
                'prev_text'    => __('Previous'),
                'next_text'    => __('Next'),
                'add_args'     => false, 
                'add_fragment' => '',  
                'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' ),
                'type' => 'list',
            )
              );
              ?>   
        </div>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif ; ?>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Если Юзер выбрал my_tax1 то он увидет список статей которые принадлежать меткам таксономии my_tax1, если выбрал my_tax2 то увидет список статей которые пренадледат меткам my_tax2